# Could I reuse scm for pipelineJobs created from a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

In my jenkins pipeline script (Jenkinsfile) I am creating pipelineJob:s using the jobDsl step, like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('create pipelines') {
      steps {
        jobDsl scriptText: """
          pipelineJob('myfolder/myname') {
            definition {
              cps {
                script(readFileFromWorkspace('Jenkinsfile.subfolder')
              }
            }
          }
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above code works fine, however I believe those jobs would be better off geting their Jenkinsfile from SCM instead.

There is the `cpsScm` variant, but how could I reuse the scm-info from the current pipeline so that I don't have to specify each parameter individually?

I would like something along the lines of:

```
// ...
// Note: this does not work, sadly :)

jobDsl scriptText: """
  pipelineJob('myfolder/myname') {
    definition {
     cpsScm = ${scm}
     scriptPath('Jenkinsfile.subfolder')
    }
  }
"""

// ...
```

So far I've come up with:

```
cpsScm {
  scm {
    git {
      remote {
        url('${scm.getRepositories()[0].getURIs()[0].toString()}')
        credentials('bitbucket-jenkins')
      }
      branch('${env.BRANCH_NAME}')
    }
  }
  scriptPath('${pipelineFile}')
}
```